# Winforms TreeView Serialization which includes the content of "TreeNode.Tag" property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

How can I (binary) serialize a "WinForm Treeview" into a file, so that also objects, which are assigned to **TreeNode.Tag** are also saved. I need **serialization** and **deserialization** (into the treeview again).
I have tried the following solution: [Saving content of a treeview to a file and load it later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868790/saving-content-of-a-treeview-to-a-file-and-load-it-later), but after deserialization all tag properties, which consists of objects in the original serialized treeview, are now = null.

Comment: Yes a custom class. Meybe the reason is, that the class definition doesn't have the [Serializable()] Attribute!?

Comment: I have added the Serializable Attribute to the custom class. During deserialization I get now the exception "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed"

Comment: All members of that custom class also need to be Serializable.

Comment: `Serialization` is not always the choice for you because sometimes it's very complicated to implement `ISerializable`, You should go for `XML` with some predefined structure/syntax to store all the needed data of your `TreeView`, saving to and loading from it is very easy.