# C#: save treeview content in a file

Tags: c#, treeview

I followed [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868790/saving-content-of-a-treeview-to-a-file-and-load-it-later), but I got an unhandled Exception (`UnauthorizedAccessException`) at this line: `Stream file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create)`.

Edit: Here's my code:

```
public void SaveTree(TreeView tree, string filename)
    {
        using (Stream file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(file, tree.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList());
        }
    }

    SaveTree(treeView1, path); //in the SaveButton_Click method
```

Is someone can help me?

Comment: Avoid giving external links, instead try to add the snippet inline.

Comment: I'll remember for next time, sorry.

Comment: @Newokmyne You need to edit your question and provide the code. Also, you need to tell that, at what statement you are getting the error.

Comment: Edited. But the error is found now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s67691sb(v=vs.110).aspx) you're receiving this exception when:

path specified a file that is read-only and access is not Read.

-or-

path specified a directory.

-or-

The caller does not have the required permission.

-or-

mode is Create and the specified file is a hidden file.

Comment: This is the best answer considering lack of additional information in question. Voting up.

Comment: I found my mistake by reading this: 

path specified a directory.

Cause my FileName attribute had the directory value. not the file name. Thanks.