# Export list of treeview to text file in c#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a treeview and I want to export treeview parent nodes, child to .txt file. but when I export .txt file the format looks very bad. 
I found this topic but its not helpful for me. There is a another way ?

[Saving content of a treeview to a file and load it later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868790/saving-content-of-a-treeview-to-a-file-and-load-it-later)

I want to like this in .txt file

1. Main Folder

   - Sub Folder

     - .docx or .zip file
     - .docx or .zip file 2
   - Sub Folder 2

     - .txt file

but in my .txt file like this.

ÿÿÿÿ          WSystem.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089   ›System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]   _items_size_version  System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[]                        System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode      
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode    TextToolTipTextName  IsChecked
ImageIndexImageKeySelectedImageIndexSelectedImageKey
ChildCount  children0   children1   children2   children3   children4   children5   children6   children7   children8   children9
children10
children11
children12
children13
children14
children15
children16
children17
children18
children19
children20
children21UserData    System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode         +ASP .NET MVC YazÄ±lÄ±mcÄ±larÄ±n YÃ¼kseliÅŸi                                             
           
                                                                                                         IC:\Users\asd\Desktop\ASP .NET MVC YazÄ±lÄ±mcÄ±larÄ±n YÃ¼kseliÅŸi   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   TextToolTipTextName IsChecked
ImageIndexImageKeySelectedImageIndexSelectedImageKey
ChildCount  children0   children1   children2   children3   children4UserData    System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode         1-ASP.NET MVC GiriÅŸ                                                  !       "       #       $   %   ^C:\Users\asd\Desktop\ASP .NET MVC

this my code

```
public static void SaveTree(TreeView tree, string filename)
    {
        using (Stream file = File.Open(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\myFile.txt.", FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(file, tree.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write the tree View in the Text File , you can go through the following code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnCreateTreeData();
    }

    private void btnCreateTreeData()
    {
        // create buffer for storing string data
        System.Text.StringBuilder buffer = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        // loop through each of the treeview's root nodes
        foreach (TreeNode rootNode in treeView1.Nodes)
            // call recursive function
            BuildTreeString(rootNode,buffer);
        // write data to file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\treeTest.txt", buffer.ToString());
    }

    private void BuildTreeString(TreeNode rootNode,System.Text.StringBuilder buffer)
    {
        buffer.Append(rootNode.Text);
        buffer.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (TreeNode childNode in rootNode.Nodes)
            BuildTreeString(childNode,buffer);
    }
```

[image: Tree View in Form]
[image: Tree View Saved in .txt File]

Comment: why ref StringBuilder? isn't a StringBuilder reference type already?

Comment: Thanks for your help. its works for me.  I add this line for your code. There is a short way ?

foreach (TreeNode childNode in rootNode.Nodes)
            {
                if(childNode.Level == 1)
                {
                    buffer.Append("\t");
                }
                else if(childNode.Level == 2)
                {
                    buffer.Append("\t\t");
                }